# Unmanaged code calling causes a WCF process to crash

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed-c++

I have a class which includes managed code calling to unmanaged code via C++\CLI wrapper.
Where running the class in a console application produces no errors.
But when I wrapped it up with a WCF service the application crashes when the code reaches the point of calling unmanaged code.

The problem is when passing a const wchar_t* variable as input to the unmanaged code:

```
String^ text = … // Unicode Encoded text;  
const wchar_t* chars = reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>    ((Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(string)).ToPointer());  
unmanaged_class::Process(chars);
```

Also tried this with no luck:

```
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> chars = ...
```

The application just shutdown without any exception.

I am working on Windows Server 2008 64 bit machine with .NET 4.0.
The application is configured to run on 64bit platform.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Doron.

Comment: Please provide details of the exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem was buried in the unmanaged code which is 3rd party code who had a bug and crashed in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You invoked undefined behavior somewhere in your unmanaged code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a completely wild guess, but shouldn't the `chars` pointer be pinned?

```
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> chars = ...
```

Another wild guess: does it need to be kept alive using `GC::KeepAlive( chars );` after the unmanaged call?

Comment: Another wild guess: could you use `PtrToStringChars` instead of `StringToHGlobalUni`?